# Formal definition of a mesh

Tags: mesh

For my master thesis, I need to have a formal definition of a mesh (if several definitions, the one used in Blender), in a mathemathical point of view. So "geometric model described by vertices, edges and faces, ..." is not enough. And I can't seem to find good literature giving the definition.

Sorry if my request seems stupid.

Comment: [This wikipdia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh) article has a good definition.

Comment: I already saw it but it doesn't express, for example, the fact that two polygons from a mesh either share a common edge or do not intersect.. I need something really formal. Thanks anyway for your response :)

Comment: I'm not sure there is agreement on a formal definition of what a mesh is within the Blender community, at least when I went looking for this some time back, I couldn't locate a formal definition. Further, I would note that based upon how I've seen different experienced blenderheads.use the word, there is no agreement that for a set of vertices to be a mesh, polygons  in that mesh must either share a common edge, or not intersect.

Comment: @Chaton you may have more luck piggybacking on the defintions found in [Graph Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) and [Topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology), and valid mesh vs invalid mesh (ie Blender allows an edge to be shared by 3 faces, which can be handy while editing, but it breaks assumptions that some functions make about how meshes are constructed..and is considered invalid)

Comment: Your masters Thesis.. oh! i don't think i'm qualified to answer this...